# Cannot detect input in void OnCollisionEnter()

Tags: c#, collision-detection, unity

Code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
       {
            // do something
       }
}
```

Of course, this code does not work. What I intend to do: "After collision, if the user is pressing down, do something". How can we write this another way? I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think you want to open the door from any side panel or standing on any special block? something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
var timeSinceCollision = 999;

void Update() {
    timeSinceCollision += Time.deltaTime;
    if(timeSinceCollision < 0.5 && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        // do something
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter() {
    timeSinceCollision = 0;
}
```

The 0.5 makes it so that there's a bit of allowable tolerance for when the player collides with whatever and them being able to perform the action (no one is going to be able to press the button the same frame the collision occurs on: ideally that would be 1/60th of a second!).

Edit:
Also use `GetMouseButtonDown`, which will only be true on the frame that the button is first pressed and false thereafter.  It prevents the player from holding down the button, then bumping into something, and getting the effect despite doing things out of order.

Comment: Instead of adding frame time every frame, it would be better to store `Time.time` on action and do `Time.time - storedTime < maxTime`.

Comment: Can you please upload an example project? Your code doesn't seem to be working for me...

Comment: @SamedTarıkÇETİN why is that?

Comment: @Draco18s There may be small delays between frames. It's always better to use exact time, which is independent from deltaTime or delay between frames.

Comment: The small delay between frames is in fact, the `Time.deltaTime`. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html `Time.time` is also "time at the beginning of this frame and returns the same value every time it is polled in a given frame. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html Your method and mine would have exactly identical results in Unity.

Comment: @Draco18s No, certainly. `Time.deltaTime` returns the duration of the last frame before current. It has nothing to do with delay or something else. And `Time.time` is the time passed in seconds since startup.

Comment: @SamedTarıkÇETİN No, Time.time is the number of seconds from the game start *at the beginning of the current frame.* "The time at the beginning of this frame (Read Only)."Also, both Time.time and Time.deltaTime also scale on Time.timeScale, so it's not even guaranteed to match the system clock. "Except for realtimeSinceStartup, timeScale affects all the time and delta time measuring variables of the Time class."

Answer (score 0):

I think you scenario is to stand over a special block then do something or open up the door from side panel. In block type case `OnCollision` is OK but in door type case I'd recommend `OnTrigger`, well according to your code, use `OnCollisionStay` instead of `OnCollisionEnter`

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision col)
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
       {
            // do something
       }
}
```

Comment: I considered a trigger volume as well, but immediately thought of wall-jumping, which could not be a trigger.  Depending on exact needs, `OnCollisionStay` may be a better solution.